# Stream network using multiple cell thresh holds inArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, arc-hydro

I'm trying to create a stream network with drainagelines formed at varying thresh holds throughout a drainage basin. Is there any way of doing with Arc and still creating a stream network that is fully connected?

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough for me to figure out what you are asking. How do you want the thresholds to vary? Are the thresholds based on flow accumulation, weighted flow accumulation, or something else? If you can come up with a systematic method for how you want to vary the threshold then the answer is probably yes.

Comment: The thresholds are based on flow accumulation and vary based on distance from the drainage output

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Flow Length in ArcGIS which measures flow length from either a downstream point or upstream points (upstream is based on the longest flow path).  You could do a series of Con statements on a reclassified flow length raster.  For example, maybe if flow length exceeds 2.4 km then the threshold for flow accumulation must be X or greater.  If flow length is less than 2.4 km then flow accumulation must be Y or greater to be considered a stream.  It would also be possible to implement this in a continuous fashion instead of as a series of if-then statements.